# Question about microaerophilic parasite tolerance for oxygen

Tags: parasitism

Does anyone know what is the maximal concentration of oxygen that can be tolerated by the parasite *Giardia intestinalis*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer: 50-60 µM O<sub>2</sub> is ok; 80 µM is toxic.**

[*Giardia lamblia*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giardia_lamblia) (aka *intestinalis*) is a microaerophilic intestinal parasite.

According to:

> Lloyd et al. (2000) [The microaerophilic flagellate Giardia intestinalis: oxygen and its reaction products collapse membrane potential and cause cytotoxicity.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/11101669) Microbiology 146: 3109 - 3118

Giardia colonises the upper intestine, and the oxygen concentration there has been measured at 60 µM. At oxygen concentrations up to 50 µM the organism can scavenge oxygen; above 80 µM oxygen inhibits the oxygen-scavenging process. In this paper the authors used 10% air (equivalent to 25 µM oxygen) to characterise  oxygen toxicity.

The source of oxygen sensitivity was investigated by:

> Li and Wang (2006) [A likely molecular basis of the susceptibility of Giardia lamblia towards oxygen](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16359329) Molecular Microbiology 59: 202 - 211

These authors propose that the enzyme DT-diaphorase, previously suggested as a component of the oxygen detoxification system promotes the formation of reactive oxygen species which lead to death. Thus they found that overproduction increased sensitivity to oxygen, whereas a knock-down decreased sensitivity. This work does not, however, use controlled microaerophilic conditions.